# Image doesn't show in Xamarin.forms (PCL)

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an image withn name `fb.png` and it's in root project(prtable) and I add this image to `Resource>drawble` in Droid project.

Thees is my `MainPage.xaml` code:

```
 <Image x:Name="img1"></Image>
```

And Thees is my `MainPage.xaml.cs` code:

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ImageSource img = ImageSource.FromResource("App2.fb.png");
        img1.Source = img;
        img1.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
        img1.BackgroundColor = Color.Navy;

     }
```

What changed is need that image will be appeared?

Comment: You say your image is called fb.png but in your code you are calling it "App2.fb.png". You need to use "fb.png" in your ImageSource.FromResource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is saved in the Resources/Drawable directory, then you use FromFile, not FromResource.  FromResource is used for images packaged as embedded resources in your built library.

You also need to specify the exact name of the file as it appears in Resources/Drawable, so this should do it:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ImageSource img = ImageSource.FromFile("fb.png");
    img1.Source = img;
    img1.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;
    img1.BackgroundColor = Color.Navy;

 }
```

Comment: Other things to try: make sure fb.png in your Android project in Resources/drawable has a BuildAction of AndroidResource. Then post your entire MainPage.xaml file, as a container view might be causing problems.  And be more specific about what you mean by "it doesn't work." Is it that the image isn't showing up?  It's crashing?

Comment: I set `buildAction` from `content` to `AndroidResource` And image is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full implementation of MVVM bound image resource to Image control. You need to set your viewmodel as the context of your page where the XAML is. Also accessing as "App2.fb.png" seems odd, it should just be fb.png. That might be a simpler fix.. just rename the image source to the exact name of the image as listed in Droid > resources

**XAML**

```
<Image
Aspect="AspectFit"
Source="{Binding PropertyImageStatusSource}">
```

**Base ViewModel**

Have your viewmodels inherit from a viewmodel base class so INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented on your accessors universally.

```
    public class _ViewModel_Base : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        //figure out what is getting set
        public virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);



            return true;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        //attach handler with property name args to changing property, overridable in inheriting classes if something else needs to happen on property changed
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
Public MyViewModel : _ViewModel_Base 
{
    private string ImageStatusSource = "fb.png";
    public string PropertyImageStatusSource
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref ImageStatusSource, value); }
        get { return ImageStatusSource; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't work. I have put above codeBehind in `public MainPage()` method?

Comment: I think it may actually be the way you are naming the resource. Updated answer to reflect.

Comment: Wish people would say why they down vote. The property changed base view model method is text book MVVM Xamarin. The view model does nothing but set an encapsulated property to bind to. This approach is used in my own enterprise apps and will be found in https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/ ; I am always open to discourse if there is a better way to approach it say so instead of down voting with no explanation.